# Hashtable overwriting issue in java

Tags: java, arraylist, hashtable, overwrite

I am studying java and I am having trouble using `put` to add data into a Java hashtable.

I have this code

```
double finalIDF = 0.0;
double finalIDF = 0.0;
double finalBM = 0.0;

ArrayList<Double> finalTMlist = new ArrayList<Double>();
 Hashtable<String, ArrayList<Double>> BM25TFIDF = new Hashtable<String, ArrayList<Double>>();
 String[] bm25QueryList // this is the array to store strings like {hey , good , by}

 for(int finalindex = 0; finalindex < bm25QueryList.length ; finalindex++)
{
actualTFvalueforEachDoc.clear();
finalTMlist.clear();
finalIDF = 0.0;
finalIDF = htBM25IDF.get(bm25QueryList[finalindex]);
finalTMlist = tfForAlldoc.get(bm25QueryList[finalindex]);


 for(int innerfinal = 0 ; innerfinal < finalTMlist.size() ; innerfinal++ ){
 finalTM =finalTMlist.get(innerfinal);
finalBM =  finalIDF * finalTM;
actualTFvalueforEachDoc.add(finalBM); 
finalTM = 0.0;
finalBM = 0.0;   }
 BM25TFIDF.put(bm25QueryList[finalindex], actualTFvalueforEachDoc);
 System.out.println("Right before final step after BM25TFIDF " + BM25TFIDF);  }
```

I would like to put the `ArrayList<Double>` into the hashtable using a `String` key.

The first time through the loop I got the key `"orange"`

> ```
> Right before final step after BM25TFIDF {orange=[1.1698113207547172, 1.0508474576271187, 0.8682367918523235, 1.6330439988027539, 0.8938401048492793, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0133729569093612, 0.0]}
> ```

which is fine

However, when I insert the second arraylist with second string key `"bye"` I get

> Right before final step after BM25TFIDF {orange=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.238037326690413, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], bye=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.238037326690413, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]}

It is overwriting the first arraylist. I used string array to change the key every time, so it shouldn't be happen.

I am not really sure the reason that it keeps over writing.

does anyone know the reason ?

Comment: You're putting the same list into the table twice because you only ever do `new ArrayList<...>()` once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't do `finalTmList.clear()` in your for loop. That will clear the list pointed to by the `finalTmList`, and subsequently for all the reference pointing to that list.

Since, when you add a list to the `Map`, you are not adding a copy of your `List`, rather a `copy` of your `List Reference`, that points to the same `List`. So, any change you make to that `list` with that reference, or any reference pointing to the list, will be reflected in all the reference.

You should rather create a new list in your for loop, for each entry of your Map: -

```
finalTMlist = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

Move the above statement inside your first for loop.

```
for(int finalindex = 0; finalindex < bm25QueryList.length ; finalindex++) {
    finalTMlist = new ArrayList<Double>();
    // Your rest code.
```

And follow the same thing for `actualTFvalueforEachDoc.clear()` also, whatever it is, as I can't see the declaration in the code.

Comment: thanks it works i changed actualTFvalueforEachDoc and finalTMlist to new ArrayList<Double>();. then it works fines. i was thinking that it is all local variable(i was thinking that it's ok to clear). Can you explain about reference if you are ok ?

Comment: @DcRedwing.. Edited the first paragraph. You can see it.

Comment: @DcRedwing.. Added some more content.

Answer (score 1):

You should make a new `ArrayList` for each entry in the map.

Comment: thanks!!! it works!!! by the was , what is difference betwen ".clear()" and " new ArrayList" ?

Comment: @DcRedwing this is a long discussion about OOP approach, in short, object variable are references not values, so putting the same list in the map, even they are in different entries, will point to the same list, so `.clear()` will clear the list in **all** entries, while a new list will allow distinction of one list to the other.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new array list before start a new iteration

```
actualTFvalueforEachDoc = new ArraList<Double>();
```